# How to move a file to trash in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I know its a dumb question but somehow the command i type is not working

```
set deleteFile to srcTemp & "Archive.zip"
--deleteFile path is something like this /Users/home/Desktop/Archive.zip    
tell application "Finder"
    move POSIX file "" & deleteFile & "" to trash
    --move file "\"" & destNoQuote & "Archive.zip\"" to trash
    empty the trash
end tell
```

But I get an error saying can't find the POSIX file.

Comment: deleting the trash is something you should never put into a script unless you know that the user who'll be running the script knows about this. I, for instance, hardly ever empty my trash, because I expect to be able to recover previously files sometimes. If I'd run your script, expecting it only to move something to the trash, but it then empties the trash without my consent, I'd get pretty upset about that.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Here's another method of your entire script in one line:

```
do shell script "rm -Rf " & quoted form of (srcTemp & "Archive.zip")
```

This will force remove your file and it doesn't just go to your trash, it's gone.

Answer (score 9):

I know that many people use the posix file command inside the Finder tell block of code however that's a mistake. The posix file command is not a Finder command, it's an applescript command, and therefore should not be in the Finder block if possible. This is true for all commands actually. You should only tell an application to perform the commands you can find inside of its applescript dictionary otherwise you will see unexpected behavior... as you are finding.

As such this is how you should write your code...

```
set deleteFile to srcTemp & "Archive.zip"
set posixFile to POSIX file deleteFile
--deleteFile path is something like this /Users/home/Desktop/Archive.zip    
tell application "Finder"
    move posixFile to trash
    empty the trash
end tell
```

Comment: +1 Although in Nayan's defense, there is a move command in there as well. You are right though, it's best to separate them.

Comment: For the record: POSIX file is a global class, not a command. No need to separate them.

Comment: @bazzie, agreed it's a class but what is a global class? Posix file is in the standard additions dictionary and I don't see anything in its definition that indicates "global". I'd like to understand what you mean so can you point me to some literature about your comment?

Comment: @regulus6633: By global classes I mean classes that have the same meaning in every context. Like classes defined in a scripting addition for instance. In other words the class is defined in the global name space.

Comment: @bazzie, I'm still unsure about "global". For example adayzdone mentions "move". That's a standard applescript command however the Finder supports some standard commands. You can see the standard suite of commands the Finder supports in its dictionary. Thus you can use "move" inside a Finder block with confidence. However POSIX file is not a standard command the Finder has imported and thus you can't expect it will always work as expected inside a Finder block.

Comment: @regulus6633: First, again, POSIX file is a class not a command. You are right about the fact that it's no guarantee that an command will support every class, especially application commands supporting classes defined in a scripting addition. So the question is if Finder's move command support furl (POSIX file) objects, or can an furl object be coerced into a file object. Remember that objects (class) handling is part of AppleScript and runs locally unlike commands (events) who can be executed remotely and therefore most osax commands should be used locally.

Comment: @bazzie, I keep mentioning a command because there's a coercion that takes place. An action. The text class must be coerced to the posix file class. I agree that once it's a posix file object the Finder can handle it. But it's not a posix file until the text is coerced and that's what the Finder has trouble doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58402/discussion-between-dj-bazzie-wazzie-and-regulus6633).

Comment: @regulus6633 Thanks for the reply, but it didnt work.